# Kubernetes, Unable to connect to the server: EOF

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

**Environment** of kubectl: Windows 10.

**Kubectl** version: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe

Hello. I've just installed Kubernetes cluster at Google Cloud Platform. Then applied the next command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster --zone europe-west1-b --project my-project
```

It successfully added the credentials at `%UserProfile%\.kube\config`
But when I try `kubectl get pods` it returns `Unable to connect to the server: EOF`. My computer accesses the internet through corporate proxy. How and where could I provide cert file for the kubectl so it could use the cert with all the requests? Thanx.

Comment: I assume you have Google Closud SDK installed. Try removing kubectl you installed and install the one coupled with SDK by running `gcloud components install kubectl`. Then run command you quoted again and try to get pods again.

Answer (score 0):

You would get EOF if there is no response from kubectl API calls in a certain time(Idle time is set 300 sec by default).

Try increasing cluster Idle time or maybe you might need VPN to access those pods (something like those)